# Android Realm Insert on conflict ignore

Tags: android, realm

Does anyone know a way how to solve a problem? 
I need to implement data storage with Realm.

I receive from network JSON object convert him to realm object `Card` and save it. I expand `Card` object with extra field `favorite` and change it manually from an application.

Every time when network operation executes `insertOrUpdate` wipes value, and `insert` throws an exception 'RealmPrimaryKeyConstraintException' because I have `@PrimaryKey` definition.

Is there exist in Realm feature how to use an insert with a particular update on Insert with Ignore?

Answer (score 1):

```
Card card = realm.where(Card.class).equalTo(CardFields.ID, cardId).findFirst(); // https://github.com/cmelchior/realmfieldnameshelper
if(card == null) {
    card = realm.createObject(Card.class, cardId);
}
card.setFavorite(true);
```

Or

```
Card card = realm.where(Card.class).equalTo(CardFields.ID, cardId).findFirst(); // https://github.com/cmelchior/realmfieldnameshelper
if(card == null) {
    card = new Card();
    card.setId(cardId);
}
card.setFavorite(true);
realm.insertOrUpdate(card);
```

Basically, if you don't want to overwrite the object, then you should query it and manipulate it, otherwise create it.

Comment: It helps, I adapter a bit.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce What would be your answer if there are a large number of objects instead of one, would you be suggesting iterating over them ?

Comment: You can also use https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmResults.html#setValue-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object- in newer versions thankfully